# JLabel Update from another class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, increment

I am currently having an issue incrementing a points counter in combination with a `MouseListener` event. Here is my current Progress so far (with some irrelevant code removed)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class Checkers extends JFrame
{
    Random random = new Random();
    private final int ROWS = 2;
    private final int COLS = 5;
    private final int GAP = 2;
    private final int NUM = ROWS * COLS;
    private int x;
    public static int score;
    private JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS,COLS, GAP,GAP));
public  JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel ("score: " + score);

    private MyPanel [] panel = new MyPanel[NUM];
    private Color col1 = Color.RED;
    private Color col2 = Color.WHITE;
    private Color tempColor;

    public Checkers()
    {
        super("Checkers");
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setBoard();
    }

    //pane background colour and the size of this pane.
    pane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));


    //pane background colour and size of this pane.
    pane2.setBackground(Color.white);
    pane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

    //directions on the board where these panes appear.
    add(pane, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(pane2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    pane2.add(lbl1);



    pane2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

And the MyPanel class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    public MyPanel() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        Checkers.score++;

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { 
    }
}
```

**Expected Result** - Once one of the smaller panels within the first pane are clicked, the `score` counter in pane2 is increased by 1, and this keeps going until they have all been clicked and `score` can't further be increased.

**Current Result** - The `score` does increment, but not in the way it should, instead, the points carry over to the next instance of the GUI (eg, if 3 panels are clicked in the first instance, the points will still stay 0 in this first instance, but once a new GUI is created, the points counter will be 3) which is not what i'm after.

Any help/guidance welcome.

Comment: Also repaint lbl1

Comment: I'm working on repainting and colors after main functionality is achieved.